# I happend to chmod 755 my whole /usr/ dir

Tags: permissions, sudo, chmod, dolphin, appimage

I happend to change my whole /usr/ dir files to -rwxr-xr-x with command "sudo chmod 775 -R /usr/"
now I firguire out that some special binary files like "su" "chkpaswd"and "sudo" should have the privilege
of setuid ,and I have use chmod to return them back to fix same authority problem.
But still have some mistory trouble like I cant use dolphin to mount the dev automaticly or use kwrite to rewrite some files by input passwd.It just says u dont have right to operate:Not authorized to perform operation
and now ,I cant just open the appimage because of

Cannot mount AppImage, please check your FUSE setup.
You might still be able to extract the contents of this AppImage
if you run it with the --appimage-extract option.
See https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/FUSE
for more information
open dir error: No such file or directory

I use debian 10 base os ubuntu 20.04 ,and this pic is what i have in /usr/.
I did this dangerous operation because I want to use CAE on oridinary user.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhjW7.png)

So ,can some handsome guys to told me are there any special files like "sudo" in dir /usr/ that I dont know?

Thanks!!QwQ

Comment: How are we to know what applications you've installed on your system (thus what directories you have in /usr/), we currently don't even know your OS & release, nor if you're asking about a desktop, server or some other system.  The easiest fix is via restoration of data from backups.

Comment: Basically, you don't need to change the files (and dirs) privilege of `/usr`.

Comment: Does [this reference](https://www.maketecheasier.com/file-permissions-what-does-chmod-777-means/?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=12052021) help your understanding of File permissions?

Answer (score 0):

This is what we refer to as a "fatal error". It would be very tedious and lengthy to get to know the required file permission of every system file, then correct the permissions.  In practice, the only solution here is a reinstall.

Note that you can reinstall without reformatting the system file system. Doing so will rather work as a "repair", updating all of your system files but leaving installed programs and system configuration intact. Also user configuration is preserved because user home folders are not deleted.

Comment: very thankful ,So if I reinstall my system by not format the disk ,I wont lose my data ,right?  but the install program notice me that I have to use my free space to install the system . If I redistribute my disk ,wont it auto format my disk?

Comment: No, but you do have a fully updated backup of your user data before you start this operation anyway. There is always a possibility something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I spend my space time to start a virt system of Ubuntu,and try to figure out the difference between the origin one and my broken one.
After I modify the special right of many key files ,it really help of solving almost every problems.I say like that because maybe there`re still some thing I didnt find yet.
follow are some files which have setuid right may help people like me to fix serious authrioty problems :

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xj2fe.png)